# Visual studio 2017: Razor views- HtmlHelper doesn't contain methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

ASP.Net MVC 5 project is working fine in VS 2015. 
If I open it in VS2017 from the same place on the same machine I got errors in Razor views like:
"'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlHelper' could be found"
"The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context"
[errors window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZMOq.png)

I looked for similar errors but cannot find anything about VS 2017.

Comment: Most likely because of version errors in your `web.config.cs` files.